# how to printk the return value of void * ioremap_nocache()?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

how i print the value of the address returned by the function ioremap_nocache with printk?

```
void * ioremap_nocache (unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size);
```

http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux-mandocs/2.6.4-cset-20040312_2111/ioremap_nocache.html

I need to know the value of the virtual address stored to debug functions open, read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both `%lu` or `%p` to print a pointer. They have different representation

```
void *pointer = ioremap_nocache(phys_addr, size);
unsigned long cast = pointer;
printk("%lu - %p", cast, pointer);    // '15294563 - 0x499602d2'
```

This work also with `printf()`

Comment: Thanks, I chose to use% p is more useful, since it does not change the definition of the variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use follows

```
unsigned long x = ioremap_nocache (addr, size);  

printk(" %lu",x);
```

Comment: An `unsigned long` requires `%lu`.